# Created A record for subdomain; DNS not updating/propagating?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am having the worst time with GoDaddy and DNS propagation. I have created an A record under my domain name in the Zone File, and pointed it at the hosting package located under my GoDaddy account. The domain name is countdownevents.com. The A record I have created is called "blog". In short, I want blog.countdownevents.com to point towards my newly purchased hosting package.

I have never had DNS propagation take more than a couple of hours to start taking effect. In this case, it's been almost 48 hours and it doesn't appear as though the change is taking place at all (see whatsmydns.net; not a single server shows the new IP address I want to be pointing to, which starts with "107").

Does anyone know why this might be? Every other A record I've created is working seamlessly, and GoDaddy keeps giving me the "Well technically it hasn't been a full 2 days..." run around O_O, and I know something is obviously wrong.

Any idea what that might be?

**A Record for countdownevents.com is:**

`@ 600 IN A 184.168.47.225`

**A Record for blog.countdownevents.com is:**

`blog 3600 IN A 107.180.3.91`

Note: Name servers (NS records) for countdownevents.com also point towards GoDaddy's dns servers.

**See photo**: http://mattermedia.ca/zonecap.png
[image: A records]

Comment: Exactly what records did you create? How do they appear? We can't see your screen, so take a screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Server Fault says I need a rep of 10 to post photo. Just started using this lol. See above edits for A record.

Comment: DNS records don't `propagate`. Your DNS A, CNAME, MX, etc. records don't go anywhere except to those DNS clients that ask for it. Do yourself a favor and brush up on your understanding of DNS. If this is a new DNS record then no DNS clients should have it cached, which means they should be able to resolve it immediately by querying the name servers for your domain name. If that's not happening then I would suggest reviewing your DNS zone at GoDaddy to make sure the record you created does in fact exist. You can link to a screenshot of the zone if you're unable to post a screenshot directly.

Comment: It would appear that you've created a subdomain named `blog.countdownevents.com`, not an A record named `blog.countdownevents.com`.

Comment: @joeqwerty See photo link above :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have created an additional zone for your `blog.countdownevents.com.` since it has independent `SOA` and `NS` records:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;blog.countdownevents.com.      IN      SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
blog.countdownevents.com. 3600  IN      SOA     ns15.domaincontrol.com.
                                                dns.jomax.net. 2015041701
                                                28800 7200 604800 600
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
blog.countdownevents.com. 3431  IN      NS      ns16.domaincontrol.com.
blog.countdownevents.com. 3431  IN      NS      ns15.domaincontrol.com.
```

Therefore you should either remove the additional zone to make the record from zone `countdownevents.com.` to become usable or add new `@ IN A` record to your additional `blog.countdownevents.com.` zone.

Comment: Damn; you're awesome :) Thank you SO, SO much. Fixed and working.